Effects of axial precession on a counterfactual Earth
Suppose that many millions of years ago, a butterfly flaps its wings at Earth's plate tectonics, such that in circa 3000 BC, there is a continent in the southern hemisphere which is the right size to have a large desert in the western portion between approximately 23S and 30S, but also be getting summer monsoons in the eastern portion—summer moonsoons powerful enough to give you a large river running east to west through the desert (assuming suitable topography).
While the continents of this counterfactual Earth are all different, the orbital parameters etc. are all the same, so if I'm reading my historical astronomical data correctly, then circa 3000 BC, perihelion should happen some time in the southern spring, but on a scale of centuries it will tend to get later in the year, moving in the direction of the southern summer. What sort of effects on climate patterns would you expect in a scenario like that? Would you expect dramatic shrinkage of the desert from say 3000 BC to 1000 BC, or anything like that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There seem to be multiple questions here.  Unfortunately, "what would the effect of X be on the climate" type questions are very difficult, especially when X in this instance is a vague "having had milder seasons in say the 4th millenium BC".  Unless you are proposing having the exact climate and changes to it become a major story point, I suggest that you can use and modify existing areas of Earth as much as you like.  (It's also not clear why you don't want the Nile Valley to be recognisable to readers, though that it up to you.)

That comment from the automated Community BOT is a red flag. It means your question has failed a "good question" heuristic. I agree with @KerrAvon2055 that part of the problem is you're asking more than one question on a service that permits only one question, but another problem is that you're rambling - a lot - on a service that expects specific, well-focused questions. I took a crack at editing your question to remove the fluff and failed because you appear to be trying to create a scientifically realistic world without actually understanding the science behind it - and the bite is too big.

Further, it's important that you understand the strengths and weaknesses of the service you're trying to use because it's not designed to replace an education. Please carefully read the [tour] and the following three Help Center pages: [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and help center. Knowing what is expected by the service owners will help considerably.

I'm not expecting a single unique right answer, so much as trying to get at what the space of possibilities looks like. Though maybe the answer is "the space of possibilities is so wide you should do whatever you want".

@TopherBrennan You need to be that's how this works, you ask one question we answer it in as many different ways as people who think they have a unique perspective and you pick the answer that works best for you. I count three explicit and several implied questions in there, we don't cover that much ground in one go. We stick to one question so that the answers are general enough to be useful to others with similar issues.

Your planet is not Earth, because the geography described does not correspond to any place on Earth: there is no major river flowing east to west in the sothern hemisphere, and there hasn't been one for a very long time. As a consequence, everything else is irrelevant. It is a different planet, with its own orbital parameters, its own axial precession, its own alien Milankovitch cycles, and, most importantly, its own geography. Just make up the conditions as required by the story. (And I don't get the reference to 1,300 BCE. It is not Earth, so why link it to Earth history?)

Okay, I've rewritten the question, not sure if it's an improvement, but I hope it is.

@AlexP The thing I have noticed is that fantasy world-builders creating worlds allegedly unconnected to Earth have a tendency to wind up creating "Earth, but with different continents". Golarion—the Pathfinder RPG setting—explicitly has years exactly the same length as Earth's years, and even when stuff like that isn't explicit it often seems to be assumed. So I thought, why not make "Earth but with different continents" explicit down to axial tilt, perihelion, etc.?

@TopherBrennan Per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. You may elect to not select a single right answer, but you are obligated to write your question as if you would. That's the way Stack Exchange is designed and expected to be used.


"Would you expect dramatic shrinkage of the desert from say 3000 BC to 1000 BC?"
In real geography we do have a vast desert (or semi-desert in some works, which call it a semi-arid sandy savanna) in western Africa, right between 20° and 30° southern latitude: the Kalahari. As it happens, there is also a river flowing east to west through its southernmost part: the Orange River. Although the Orange River is very important for South Africa, it cannot be called a great river; its discharge is only about 470 cubic meters per second, about one sixth of the discharge of the Nile, and the river is not navigable for any significant distance.
The thing is, the last time the Kalahari was green and lush was between 30,000 and 10,000 years BP, or between 28,000 BCE and 8,000 BCE. As far as we know, in 3,000 BCE the Kalahari was as desolate as it is now.
Yes, I know that years before present means years before 1950. The dates before the current era were rounded to the closest thousand years, to avoid giving the impression that they had three significant figures.
So that no, I wouldn't expect major changes in the size of the desert between 3,000 BCE and 1,000 BCE. But this shouldn't be taken as if I would not accept such a change in a work of fiction wihtout even giving it a second thought. It is known that the boundaries of deserts change over time for all sorts of poorly understood reasons, and that conditions in said deserts also change over time. For example, 2,000 years ago the Roman army crossed the Sahara on foot, and not once but twice.

Remember that internal geological forces are always at play alongside the external forcings of the Milankovitch cycles, and that they can be stronger and can have dramatic effects.
Speaking of the Kalahari, about 10,000 years ago a tectonic uplift dramatically changed the hydrology of the northeastern part of the area. The courses of the Okavango and the Cuando rivers were blocked, which led to the dessication of the mighty Lake Makgadikgadi and the formation of the inland Okavango Delta.
Just a bit further east, 20,000 years ago the Zambezi River used to flow south and discharge into the Limpopo River; the same epeirogenic movement blocked the southwards flow, and forced the river to turn east through the Batoka Gorge and form the famous Victoria Falls.
In another part of the world, consider the dramatic changes in hydrography caused by the continuous rise of the Himalayas at some poorly known point between 8,000 and 2,000 BCE: the Sutlej River turned west to join the Indus, and the Yamuna River turned east to join the Ganges, leading to the dwindling of the once impressive Ghaggar-Hakra into the sorry intermittent stream it is today.



Nit: are we sure the Romans didn't use camels to cross the Sahara? That's something that continues to be possible today.

@TopherBrennan: They definitely used pack animals of some kind to carry the equipment and provisions and water. We know for sure that in the 1st century BCE and 1st century CE Roman Africa had lots of horses and mules; I am not sure that they had many camels there in that time frame. Egypt surely did have camels, but for the Romans Egypt was Egypt and Africa was something else entirely. (The three parts of the world were called Europe, Asia, and Libya. Only later did the name Africa extend over the entire third part of the world.)
